# Is this query well written? I am fairly new at this and am wondering if there is a better way to write it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
UPDATE table1  
INNER JOIN table2  
ON table1.var1=table2.var1  
SET table1.var2=table2.var2
```

My table has about 975,000 rows in it and I know this will take a while no matter what. Is there any better way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have an index on var1 in both tables to improve performance. Also consider using a tool like common_schema to break the update into chunks: http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_split.html

Comment: @ike you only need an index on table2

Comment: @Bohemian if you do it all in one chunk that's true, but if you want to break the update into smaller chunks then you need the index on both tables.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is probably more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is more for getting solutions to actual problems you're facing now, rather than optimizing or improving working code. (+1 for actually including the code and explaining why you're asking, though.) :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0):

If the standard case is that table1.Var2 already is equal to table2.var2, you may end up with an inflated write count as the database may still update all those rows with no functional change in value.

You may get better performance by updating only those rows which have a different value than the one you desire.

```
UPDATE table1  
INNER JOIN table2  
ON table1.var1=table2.var1  
SET table1.var2=table2.var2
WHERE (table1.var2 is null and table2.var2 is not null OR
       table1.var2 is not null and table2.var2 is null OR
       table1.var2 <> table2.var2)
```

---

**Edit:** Nevermind... MySQL only updates on actual changes, unlike some other RDBMS's (MS SQL, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN
       table2  
       ON table1.var1 = table2.var1  
    SET table1.var2 = table2.var2;
```

A priori, this looks fine.  The major issue that I can see would be a 1-many relationship from `table1` to `table2`.  In that case, multiple rows from `table2` might match a given row from `table1`.  MySQL assigns an arbitrary value in such a case.

You could fix this by choosing one value, such as the `min()`:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN
       (select var1, min(var2) as var2
        from table2
        group by var1
       ) t2
       ON table1.var1 = t2.var1  
    SET table1.var2 = t2.var2;
```

For performance reasons, you should have an index on `table2(var1, var2)`.  By including both columns in the index, the query will be able to use the index only and not have to fetch rows directly from the table.